# <input type="date" > looks different on page (WebView)

Tags: html, css, input, calendar

In an html page, there is an input with type=date as follows. But this date is shown as the picture below. I want the normal calendar to be opened, what could be the reason? I also want to make a note. When I try to open this calendar from any browser, there is no problem. I use it as a webview page in the mobile application and the problem occurs there.

```
<div>
<input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date">
</div>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$TMPL}/css/broadrecord.css" />
</head>
```

[image]

**Solution**:Problem solved using jquery-ui-date-picker, thanks everyone.

Comment: Each browser implements `input[type=date]` differently. Browsers even tend to use operating system standand widgets where possible. So you'll see different results depending on which platform and which browser you are using. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: actually this is not a problem i normally encounter. There is no problem when I open the page in chrome or opera right now. This is how it looks when I open this page in a mobile app(WebView) and I'm stuck. I'm using ready-made js calendars but it doesn't change @BrettDonald

Answer (score 0):

The date/time input is a standard input and can have different designs according to the browser. You might think that it looks different in every different browser.

For example:
[image]

You can also write CSS and style it to write this in a common way in every browser.

Comment: actually this is not a problem i normally encounter. There is no problem when I open the page in chrome or opera right now. This is how it looks when I open this page in a mobile app(WebView) and I'm stuck. I'm using ready-made js calendars but it doesn't change @IbrahimNergiz